# Select case within if/then

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a ToggleButton (TB) and ComboBox (CB) on a userform where if the TB.value=True, then it must determine what the CB.value is to insert the correct file.

I am using an if/then statement to address the TB.value (I have used this for the other toggles on the userform and it has been effective on its own.  To address the the CB.value, I am attempting to use a select case statement.

When I run the script with the select case statement within the if/then statement, I am not getting the file to insert.

Here is an example of my code, including how I have listed the CB to initialize:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

CreateObject (Word.Application.Documents.Add)

If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
Select Case File
    Case ComboBox1.Value = "File A"
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\File A"
    Case ComboBox1.Value = "File B"
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\File B"
    End Select
Else:
    ToggleButton1.Value = False
End If

Unload Me

End Sub



Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "File A", 0
    .AddItem "File B", 1
    End With

End Sub
```

If anyone would be able to help me figure out why I can't get the file to insert using the above method, that would be appreciated.  If there is a better way to do this, I would also love to hear that!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for that information about the redundancies.  I am still learning this, so it is quite helpful!  I will also take a look at the indenter; how I have it in the above is slightly off from where it is in my actual code (I had to insert 4 spaces before the sub, if definition, and with).  I try to start new steps without indents and anything happening within falls below and is indented.

Comment: Next time try 4 spaces *for the entire code block* ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your select case is in error:

```
Select Case ComboBox1.Value
    Case "File A"
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\File A"
    Case  "File B"
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\File B"
    End Select
```

You put what you are testing in the Select Case line and the possible outcomes in the Case lines.

Comment: A wonderful observation, thank you!  Kind of upset I missed that.  
Though that appears to correct the function of the Select Case, it does not appear to have fixed the issue where the file does not insert.

Comment: Try adding a `Case Else: msgbox "No matches found"` before the `End Select` and see if you are finding a match.

Comment: That did give a result... no matches found.  Is there another way to match the ComboBox.value= that isn't the contents of the combobox?  Sorry if that is a stupid question.

Comment: I went back and used a nested if/else and accounted for File A and File B.  That gave me the correct output, though I do not know why my nested Select Case is not doing the same thing.  Thanks for the help, Scott!